# Regex to remove first word and capitalize the first char of the second with c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove the first specific word from a phrase (for instance Write) and return the remaining words with the first capitalized.

Write your letters in the sand => Your letters in the sand

I use this code

```
var test = Regex.Replace("Write your letter in the sand", "(^Write )(.)", "$2");
```

and I get

```
test == "your letter in the sand"
```

but I don't know how to capitalize the second captured group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var text = "Write your letter in the sand";
var test = Regex.Replace(text, @"^\w+\W+(\w)", x => x.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper());
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/lyWxQO).

Here, `^\w+\W+(\w)` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(\w)` - Group 1: a word char.

The `x => x.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()` lambda expression takes the Group 1 value (the first char of the second word) and puts it back into the resulting string in place of matched text, after turning it to upper case.